# Query between has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a projects model that has the following

```
has_many :project_topics
has_many :topics, :through => :project_topics
```

I need a way to be able to query a `topic id` and have it return all the projects that have that topic. Any ideas?

```
def projects_by_topic(topic)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this. And check out [Rails guild on ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

```rb
def projects_by_topic(topic)
  project_topics = ProjectTopics.where(topic_id: topic.id)
  project_topics_ids = project_topics.map {|pt| pt.id }
  projects = Project.where(project_topic_id: project_topics_ids)
end
```